# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a chat controller with a WKInterfaceTable of canned messages and each table row is a different kind of rowController that comes with a WKInterfaceTable in WatchKit.

Each rowController references a MessageSource and MessageType which is defined in an enum.

The declaration of my enum looks good but the implementation syntax of the related dictionary needs some help.

Another issue related to the same blocks is the Swift conversion of my properties. I'm not sure if I have declared them correctly therefore they may be affecting the same blocks.

I have tried to trim as much code as possible because I know SO likes it that way.  There are a few references in different functions though so I included what was needed to keep things explicit.

Obj-C

controller.m

```
typedef enum {
MessageSourceIncoming = 1,
MessageSourceOutgoing = 2
} MessageSource;

typedef enum {
MessageTypeText = 1,
MessageTypeVoice = 2,
MessageTypeImage = 3
} MessageType;

- (void)setupTable {
_messages = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < rand()%20; i++) {
    [_messages addObject:@{@"msg":@[@"Hi", @"OK", @"Nice to meet you", @"Fine"][rand()%4], @"source":@(rand()%2), @"type":@(rand()%3)}];
}

// clear the table rows
[_table removeRowsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, _table.numberOfRows)]];
for (int i = 0; i < _messages.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *messageDic = _messages[i];
    [self insertRowForMessage:messageDic];
}
}

- (void)willActivate {
[_table scrollToRowAtIndex:_table.numberOfRows - 1];
if (_shouldSendVoice) {
    NSDictionary *messageDic = @{@"source":@(MessageSourceOutgoing), @"type":@(MessageTypeVoice), @"path":_shouldSendVoice};
    [_messages addObject:messageDic];
    [self insertRowForMessage:messageDic];
    _shouldSendVoice = nil;
}
}
```

Comment: You need to reduce this into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There is way too much code here for such a simple error.  And most likely, the simple exercise of creating the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will get you to the answer on your own.  And if not, you'll have a much better form of the same question to post here.

Comment: Stop using dictionaries for temporary data. Why `messageDic`? Why don't you just declare a `struct Message`? Why using `NSArray` in Swift?  Just create a Swift array with a specific type, e.g. `var messages: [Message] = []`. You have several problems there but all of them are caused by bad programming style and ignoring of types. You probably also have a ton of warnings.

Comment: If you get any kind of `ambiguous` error you need to give the compiler more specific information about the type in your case by an appropriate annotation. But basically I agree with @Sulthan: Use the native types and the tremendous object oriented skills and of Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
enum MessageSource: Int {
   case MessageSourceIncoming = 1
   case MessageSourceOutgoing = 2
}

enum MessageType: Int {
   case MessageTypeText = 1
   case MessageTypeVoice = 2
   case MessageTypeImage = 3
}
```

Nothing wrong with enums, however it's a question whether you need to give them integer values. You don't have to assign every value though:

```
enum MessageType: Int {
   case MessageTypeText = 1
   case MessageTypeVoice
   case MessageTypeImage
}
```

would work just fine and the values would be the same.

```
var chat = NSDictionary()
var messages = NSMutableArray()
var shouldSendVoice = NSString()
```

`chat` should probably be a Swift dictionary but we don't have enough information to set the type so I will skip it.
`shouldSendVoice` looks like a boolean, why should we assign a `NSString` to it? I am not sure how you are using that one, so I won't rename it but let's make an optional string from it.
`messages` should be a Swift array. Let's create a type for `Message`:

```
struct Message {
    let message: String?
    let source: MessageSource
    let type: MessageType
    let path: String?
}

var chat = NSDictionary() // let's ignore this
var messages: [Message] = []  // empty swift array of messages
var shouldSendVoice: String? = nil // optional String
```

Now, let's just rewrite the rest:

```
override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()

    self.table.scrollToRowAtIndex(table.numberOfRows - 1)

    // in Obj-C this was checking for nil!, we have to check explicitly in Swift
    if let shouldSendVoice = self.shouldSendVoice {
        // let's not use Dictionaries for custom objects
        let message = Message(message: nil, source: .MessageSourceIncoming, type: .MessageTypeVoice, path: shouldSendVoice)
        self.messages.append(message)

        self.insertRowForMessage(message) 
        // I think you don't want new String here, just `nil`
        shouldSendVoice = nil
    }
}

func setupTable() {
    // let's use a saner way to generate randoms
    let numMessages = Int(arc4random_uniform(20))

    self.messages = (0..<numMessages).map { _ in
       let message = // randomize the message
       let source = // randomize source
       let type = // randomize type

       return Message(message: message, source: source, type: type, path: nil)
    }

    // let's split multiple operations into separate lines to make code more readable
    let indicesToRemove = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, table.numberOfRows))
    self.table.removeRowsAtIndexes(indicesToRemove)

    // let's use for-in without using an index
    for message in messages {
        self.insertRowForMessage(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: @TokyoToo Please, don't take example from the original code, it is not good code :) The `if (shouldSendVoice) {` in Obj-C is a short for `if (shouldSendVoice != nil) {`. `NSDictionary` is not needed at all in Swift, even when you are interacting with Obj-C APIs, `NSDictionary` usually gets converted to `[String: AnyObject]`. In Swift we always want to know which types an array/dictionary holds, that's why we don't use `NSDictionary` because it cannot express types.